# Website for C debugging puzzles

Tags: c, debugging, puzzle

could you recommend some website for C debugging puzzles?

Thanks

Comment: why do you want to close this question ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take any subversion, git or other repo on the net, which contains a project written in C

Compile, run, break debug .... give back to the community. You will **never run out of challenges**

Here are some:

1. http://git.gnome.org/browse/
2. http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git;a=summary
3. http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/qemu.git
4. http://directory.fsf.org/GNU/

And millions more!

Comment: I am a beginner that wants to learn about the use of debugging, and those projects are quite complex

Comment: it is like giving a F1 racing car to somebody who wants to learn driving

Comment: +1 this answer does not deserve to be rated negatively.

Comment: @Werner - Sorry, didn't realize you were a beginner :) - Still no reason not to dive in ... you don't necessarily need to submit patches ;)